# Show that Lipchitz functions space is Banach

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Let X be a Banach space. Show that $L = \{  f:X \to \mathbb{R}: f  \text{ is Lipschitz and } f(0)=0 \}$ with norm:

$$\|f\|_{lip}= \sup \left\{ \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{||x-y||}; x \neq y \in X \right\}$$

is Banach space.

I want to get a sequence of Cauchy in $ L $ and show that converges, I'm trying to transform into a sequence of Cauchy in $\mathbb{R}$ but I'm not getting.

Comment: Try first the special case $X = [0, 1] \subset {\mathbb R}$.

Comment: This looks related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/790995/banach-space-under-the-lip-norm?rq=1.

Comment: I always have the same problem. I have a string of $ f_n $ cauchy and conclude that for n large enough: $[f_n(x)-f_m(x)]-[f_n(y)-f_m(y)] < \epsilon ||x-y||$ With this I would like to conclude something of the type $|f_n(x)-f(x)|< \epsilon||x-y||$, but i can not.

Comment: If you have a Cauchy sequence with this norm you can check that for each $x\in X$ the value $f_n(x)$ is also Cauchy and thus must admit a limit. Let $f$ be this pointwise limit, can you find an argument that shows $f_n$ converges to $f$ in your norm?

Comment: The only step I'm not getting is check that for each x∈X the value fn(x) is also Cauchy. From then on I understand everything.

Comment: This is the same as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3136994/space-of-lipschitz-functions-form-a-banach-space/3137089#3137089